# The center of $G$-$\textbf{Set}$.

Tags: category-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and let $G$-$\textbf{Set}$ be the category of $G$-sets (whose objects are sets equipped with an action of $G$ and morphisms are G-equivariant maps). Determine The center of $G$-$\textbf{Set}$.

According to the definition, the elements of $Z(G\text{-}\textbf{Set})$ are automorphisms $\psi_X: X\to X$, such that the diagram

$X\overset{\psi_X}{\to} X$

$\!\!\!f\downarrow \quad\downarrow f $

$Y\overset{\psi_Y}{\to}Y$

is commutative for any $f: X\to Y$.

How to determine the center? Any hints are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: let $\psi$ be an element of the center, and draw the naturality diagram for morphisms $G \to G$ (with the regular action of $G$ on itself). What can you deduce about $\psi_G$? What does $\psi_G$ tell you about $\psi_X$ for other $X$?